# Existing of recursive anonimous functions

Tags: php, recursion

So is recursive anonimous functions existing in nature? Especially in PHP...

```
$f = function ($node) {
    foreach ($node->operands as $operand) {
        $f($operand); // o_0
    }
}
```

Comment: Anonymous or not, that's a lovely infinite loop

Comment: It's just an example in vacuum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it's not obvious:

```
$f = function($node) use (&$f) {
    var_dump($f);
};
$f(1);
```

Outputs:

```
object(Closure)#1 (2) {
  ["static"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["f"]=>
    *RECURSION*
  }
  ["parameter"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["$node"]=>
    string(10) "<required>"
  }
}
```

Comment: In JavaScript, use `arguments.callee` to refer to the current function. I don't know about Python.